# how to fast read all excel files inside zip archive and perform operation without taking so much time?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-zipfile

starting the loop to read from two different zip archive 1st excel file and perform some processing to specific row

```
with ZipFile(Project_path) as zip_file_pro , ZipFile(Reference_path) as zip_file_ref:
    for fn_pro,(member_pro , member_ref) in enumerate(zip(zip_file_pro.namelist(),zip_file_ref.namelist())):
        df_results_ma = pd.DataFrame()
        df_results_mi = pd.DataFrame()
        xlfile_pro = zip_file_pro.open(member_pro)
        xlfile_ref = zip_file_ref.open(member_ref)

        sheet1_pro = pd.read_excel(xlfile_pro, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
        sheet2_pro = pd.read_excel(xlfile_pro, sheet_name = 'Sheet2')    
    
        sheet1_ref = pd.read_excel(xlfile_ref, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')        
        sheet2_ref = pd.read_excel(xlfile_ref, sheet_name = 'sheet2')
        x=(sheet2_pro.loc['Row 1'].sum() - sheet2_ref.loc['Row 1'].sum())*-1 
        y=(sheet1_pro.loc['Row29'].sum() - sheet1_ref.loc['Row29'].sum())*.7/1000*-1 
        df_results.loc['Specific Row',df_results.columns[3]] = (x-y)*1
```

Writing to Excel

```
        project_exl = load_workbook(file_path)
        project_exc_sheet = project_exl['1']
   
        Write_result = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine = 'openpyxl')
        Write_result.book = project_exl
        Write_result.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in project_exl.worksheets)
        df_results.to_excel(Write_result, sheet_name = 'Result_1', index = False, header=False, startrow = 12, startcol = 3)
        project_exl.save(file_path)
        Write_result.close()
```

it takes so much time to read and write to excel

Comment: How much is "so much time"?  How large are the spreadsheets?  There is a heck of a lot of processing hidden in those few lines of code.

Comment: I use for loop to read 35 excel file within zip archive, each excel is around 114 KB with around 60 Row and 80 Columns

after I process some functions on the data I extracted from each excel file, I write the data to a new excel file and keep updating that file every loop

I have also 19*2 zip files
the whole process takes around 40 min

Comment: So, you're extracting, reading, and processing 1,330 Excel files in 2,400 seconds.  That's 2 seconds each.  It's going to be hard to improve on that, especially if you need the results serialized so you can combine them.

Comment: have you tried multiprocessing it? Also worth checking out PyArrow for reading csv faster

Comment: I haven't tried multiprocessing can u help on that

Comment: Can you help on multiprocessing inside a for loop?

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing on the sheets? Please edit your question to include a sample of the and the processing.

Comment: How often do you perform this task/execution?

Comment: The processing is 7 equations like the one below
    x=(sheet2_pro.loc['Row 1'].sum() - sheet2_ref.loc['Row 1'].sum())*-1
    y=(sheet1_pro.loc['Row29'].sum() - sheet1_ref.loc['Row29'].sum())*.7/1000*-1
write to dataframe the result which is  (x-y)
then I write the whole dataframe in excel
and then open the next 2 excel file to perform the same calculations and store it to the same excel, etc

I perform this task once per week
it takes around 40 min or more

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you actually need Pandas to do process the data.  If not, this solution proposes using OpenPyXL to read the Excel files (workbooks), their sheets, and get values from cells.

To start with, I made this set-up script to try and mock your input data, which meant:

- create one Excel file with two sheets

  - each sheet has a header row, then 60 rows by 80 columns of integers (I don't know your actual types)
- the file was then written to a Pro and a Ref master Excel file
- the two master Excel files were copied 35 times each
- the 35 copies for Pro and Ref were zipped up into two master ZIP files
- the master ZIP files were copied 19 times each

I think that's the set up your comment laid out.

```py
import glob
import os
import shutil

from zipfile import ZipFile

from openpyxl import Workbook

# Create local temp dir, and then chdir to it
t_dir = "temp"
try:
    shutil.rmtree(t_dir)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
finally:
    os.mkdir(t_dir)
os.chdir(t_dir)

# Create single Excel file
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "Sheet1"
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Sheet2")

header = [f"Col{x}" for x in range(1, 81)]
ws1.append(header)
ws2.append(header)

row = list(range(1, 81))  # 80 columns
for x in range(1, 61):  # by 60 rows
    ws1.append([x * y for y in row])  # per sheet
    ws2.append([x * y for y in row])

# Save single Excel file to both Pro and Ref master files
pro_xlsx = ".pro.xlsx"
ref_xlsx = ".ref.xlsx"

wb.save(pro_xlsx)
wb.save(ref_xlsx)

# Copy each master file Excel 35 times
for i in range(1, 36):
    shutil.copy(pro_xlsx, f"pro_{i:02}.xlsx")
    shutil.copy(ref_xlsx, f"ref_{i:02}.xlsx")

# Create master ZIP with each of the 35 Excel files
pro_zip = ".pro.zip"
ref_zip = ".ref.zip"

with ZipFile(pro_zip, "w") as f_zip:
    for f_xlsx in glob.glob("pro*.xlsx"):
        f_zip.write(f_xlsx)

with ZipFile(ref_zip, "w") as f_zip:
    for f_xlsx in glob.glob("ref*.xlsx"):
        f_zip.write(f_xlsx)

# Copy each master ZIP file 19 times
for i in range(1, 20):
    shutil.copy(pro_zip, f"pro_{i:02}.zip")
    shutil.copy(ref_zip, f"ref_{i:02}.zip")
```

That got me to a point where I could run your code, and get an accurate timing:

```py
import glob
import os

from zipfile import ZipFile

import pandas as pd

os.chdir("temp")

pro_zip_files = sorted(glob.glob("pro*.zip"))
ref_zip_files = sorted(glob.glob("ref*.zip"))

for pro_zip_file, ref_zip_file in zip(pro_zip_files, ref_zip_files):
    with (
        ZipFile(pro_zip_file) as zip_file_pro,
        ZipFile(ref_zip_file) as zip_file_ref,
    ):
        for fn_pro, (member_pro, member_ref) in enumerate(zip(zip_file_pro.namelist(), zip_file_ref.namelist())):
            xlfile_pro = zip_file_pro.open(member_pro)
            xlfile_ref = zip_file_ref.open(member_ref)

            sheet1_pro = pd.read_excel(xlfile_pro, sheet_name="Sheet1")
            sheet2_pro = pd.read_excel(xlfile_pro, sheet_name="Sheet2")
            sheet1_ref = pd.read_excel(xlfile_ref, sheet_name="Sheet1")
            sheet2_ref = pd.read_excel(xlfile_ref, sheet_name="Sheet2")

            for sheet in [sheet1_pro, sheet2_pro, sheet1_ref, sheet2_ref]:
                assert sheet["Col80"].sum() == 146400

            xlfile_pro.close()
            xlfile_ref.close()

    print(f"done with ZIPs {pro_zip_file} and {ref_zip_file}")
```

and now with the OpenPyXL alternative:

```py
...
from openpyxl import load_workbook
...
...
    ...
        ...
            ...
            pro_wb = load_workbook(xlfile_pro, read_only=True)
            ref_wb = load_workbook(xlfile_ref, read_only=True)

            sheet1_pro = pro_wb["Sheet1"]
            sheet2_pro = pro_wb["Sheet2"]
            sheet1_ref = ref_wb["Sheet1"]
            sheet2_ref = ref_wb["Sheet2"]

            for sheet in [sheet1_pro, sheet2_pro, sheet1_ref, sheet2_ref]:
                rows = iter(sheet.rows)  # turn generator into iterator, so we can call next(rows)
                next(rows)  # skip header
                summed = sum((row[79].value for row in rows))
                assert summed == 146400

            pro_wb.close()
            ref_wb.close()
            xlfile_pro.close()
            xlfile_ref.close()

    ...
```

As far as I can tell those two do the same trivial process of summing the integer values in the last column.

Here's how they performed on my M1 MacBook Air (w/the 2TB (split channel) SSD):

| Process | Time (s) | Memory (MB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OpenPyXL | 38 | 35 |
| Pandas | 51 | 60 |

So, OpenPyXL runs in about 75% of the time as Pandas (and uses a little less memory); OpenPyXL only beats Pandas with the read_only=True option set, otherwise it runs slightly slower than Pandas.

No matter your machine or setup, reading the XLSX file is the bottleneck.

If the data was originally CSV to start with, with two CSVs per "workbook" to account for the two sheets, Pandas runs in 3 secs, and using Python's csv module runs in 0.3 secs.

Comment: I don't think OpenPyXL will work for my needs as I need to have dataframe of each sheet

Comment: @armhels, okay. Pandas is the first bottleneck, followed by Excel. This process will just be slow then. Good luck, and cheers :) BTW, what calculations/work are you doing with the dataframes?

Comment: I updated the code above to show you the calculations I perform using dataframe.
mainly some basic math operations